# Why is Karma not compiling TS how I expect it

Tags: typescript, karma-runner

I am trying to add karma/jasmine to an older project I have been working on, so that I can start adding unit testing to my TypeScript code.

The problem I am having is that karma is losing some module/namespace references when it is compiling the files.

TS Source:

```
/// <reference path="../../app.ts" />
module App.Module {
    'use strict';

    class MyClass extends BaseClass {

        constructor() {
            super();
        }
}
```

Built (I use a gulp task):

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    var Module;
    (function (Module) {
       'use strict';
            var MyClass = (function (_super) {
                __extends(BaseClass, _super);
                function MyClass() {
                    var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
                    return _this;
                }
                return MyClass;
            }(App.BaseClass));
    })(Module = App.Module || (App.Module = {}));
})(App || (App = {}));
```

Built with Karma (typescriptPreprocessor):

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    var Module;
    (function (Module) {
       'use strict';
            var MyClass = (function (_super) {
                __extends(BaseClass, _super);
                function MyClass() {
                    var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
                    return _this;
                }
                return MyClass;
            }(BaseClass));
    })(Module = App.Module || (App.Module = {}));
})(App || (App = {}));
```

The difference being that my normal output qualifies BaseClass as App.BaseClass, and is able to find it.

As a test, I changed the TS code to extend App.BaseClass, and code generated by Karma was *correct*, and was able to run without the error, but I don't want to have to go through my entire application fully qualifying every reference.

Is there anything I could do in the karma setup that might *fix* this?

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            'App/**/*.ts'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            '**/*.ts': ['typescript']
        },
        typescriptPreprocessor: {
            transformPath: function (path) {
                return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
            }
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, by creating a gulp task that would watch the TS files and bundle them, while Karma was running, then I get karma to watch that bundle, instead of it trying to work with TS.

```
gulp.task('tdd', function (done) {
    new karma.Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: false
    }, done).start();

    return watch(tsFiles, function () {
        console.info('TS changed');
        gulp.src([tsFiles])
            .pipe(ts({ out: 'testbundle.js', target: 'es5', removeComments: true }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./App/tests'));
    });
});
```